# How to Modify Breadcrumb Page Names for Specific Pages?

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, breadcrumb

I am using the Wordpress SEO (Yoast) plugin to display breadcrumbs on my site.

It works fine for the most part, but on a handful of pages (4 to be exact) I want to change the breadcrumb names only.

At the moment they are:

> Home > LONG CATEGORY NAME > LONG PAGE NAME

I want them to be:

> Home > CUSTOM SHORT NAME > CUSTOM SHORT NAME

I found this https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/ but I have no idea how to implement it.

I suppose I need to use the relevant to hooks in an if statement for each page that I want to alter the breadcrumbs for and insert that in my functions.php, I just have no idea how to make the if statement!

Thank you for any assistance

Answer (score 2):

We generally don't answer plugin-specific questions here so you may find more help in a Yoast-specific forum. To point you toward the right direction, though, there is a filter called `wpseo_breadcrumb_output`. In either a custom plugin or your theme's functions.php file, you can add something to the effect of

```
add_filter('wpseo_breadcrumb_output', 'change_breadcrumb_names');
function change_breadcrumb_names($output) {
    if(is_page(12)) {
        $output = str_replace('Long Page Name', 'Custom Short Page Name', $output);
    } elseif(is_page('my-page-slug')) {
        $output = str_replace('Another Long Page Name', 'Different Custom Short Page Name', $output);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

That will at least take care of the page names. Yoast doesn't document their filters well but I'm sure there is a way to filter the category also. Depends on whether you want to filter the category name on all pages that use that category  or if you want to only filter the category name on those pages where you're filtering the page title as well.

Of course, the non-code solution would be to change your page title and category name to something shorter. Sometimes it can confuse visitors if you don't use consistent names across the website.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but it simply deleted the breadcrumbs (after I added another } at the end). I'll try on the Yoast forums, thanks for trying.

Comment: Ah, I think it was missing a `return $output` line. Best of luck!

Comment: It is missing variable as a function parameter function change_breadcrumb_names($output) { ...